# Write to Json using libGDX

Tags: java, android, json, libgdx

I am new to Json and libGDX but I have created a simple game and I want to store player names and their scores in a Json file. Is there a way to do this? I want to create a Json file in `Gdx.files.localStorage` if it doesnt exist and if it does, append new data to it.

I have checked code given at :

1>[Using Json.Serializable to parse Json files](https://code.google.com/p/steigert-libgdx/source/browse/trunk/tyrian-game/src/com/blogspot/steigert/tyrian/domain/Profile.java?spec=svn18&r=19)

2>[Parsing Json in libGDX](http://jackyjjc.com/2013/10/07/parsing-json-in-libgdx-tutorial/)

But I failed to locate how to actually create a Json file and write multiple unique object values (name and score of each player) to it. Did I miss something from their codes?

This [link](http://openglized.blogspot.in/2013/06/reading-and-parsing-json-file-with.html) mentions how to load an existing json but nothing else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all i have to say that i never used the Libgdx [`Json` API](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Json.html) myself. But i try to help you out a bit.
I think this [Tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-and-writing-JSON) on github should help you out a bit.
Basicly the `Json` API allows you to write a whole object to a `Json` object and then parse that to a `String`. To do that use:

```
PlayerScore score = new PlayerScore("Player1", 1537443);      // The Highscore of the Player1 
Json json = new Json();
String score = json.toJson(score);
```

This should then be something like:

```
{name: Player1, score: 1537443}
```

Instead of `toJson()` you can use `prettyPrint()`, which includes linebreaks and tabs.

To write this to a File use:

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("scores.json");
file.writeString(score, true);         // True means append, false means overwrite.
```

You can also customize your `Json` by implementing `Json.Serializable` or by adding the values by hand, using `writeValue`.

Reading is similar:

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("scores.json");
String scores = file.readString();
Json json = new Json();
PlayerScore score = json.fromJson(PlayerScore.class, scores);
```

If you have been using a customized version by implementing `Json.Serializable` you have implemented the `read (Json json, JsonValue jsonMap)` method. If you implemented it correctly you the deserialization should work. If you have been adding the values by hand you need to create a [`JsonValue`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/JsonValue.html)`jsonFile = new JsonValue(scores)`. `scores` is the `String` of the `File`. Now you can cycle throught the childs of this `JsonValue` or get its childs by name.

One last thing: For highscores or things like that maybe the Libgdx [`Preferences`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Preferences.html) are the better choice. [Here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences) you can read how to use them.

Hope i could help.

Comment: Thank you ...I will try this code . About preferences, I am currently using preferences and it works just fine. But later on I want to add the functionality of making an online scoreboard for which I wanted to use Json files for servers.

Comment: Ah okay for that it is okay. Just remember, that `Preferences` are the only way to make data for webapps persistent. So for data like the client dependend settings (sound and so on) they are the best choice. But i think for sending and storing data on a server `Json` is a good choice.